# Are there any Marshmallow-compatible bluetooth styli?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, stylus

I've bought a Nexus 9 as a gift for my daughter for Xmas.  After reading that Android M added native support for Bluetooth styli, I'm looking to purchase one as an additional gift. I'm looking for a stylus that is highly accurate and supports varying levels of pressure and palm rejection, like the Wacom Bamboo Fineline 2 or Intuous 2. Those products only list Apple device compatibility, though.

I realise that apps need to be updated to accommodate the new APIs in Android, but can I pair either of these with the Nexus 9 in the meantime?

Answer (score -2):

Try the Adonit Dash. No palm support on Android device though.

Comment: please link the app and explain significant use in relation to the question